# AutoModelForQuestionAnswering: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, nlp-question-answering

When I initialized AutoModelForQuestionAnswering from pretrained indobenchmark/indobert-base-p1 it won’t produce any outputs and shows ValueError, below is the code:

```
from transformers import AutoModelForQuestionAnswering, AutoTokenizer

model = AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained('indobenchmark/indobert-base-p1')
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('indobenchmark/indobert-base-p1')

context = 'Sindrom Bazex: acrokeratosis paraneoplastica.'
question = 'Nama sinonim dari Acrokeratosis paraneoplastica.'

inputs = tokenizer(question, context, return_tensors='pt')
outputs = model(**inputs)

inputs, outputs
```

The error shown is:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last) /tmp/ipykernel_28/2363476019.py in <module>
      3 
      4 inputs = tokenizer(question, context, return_tensors='pt')
----> 5 outputs = model(**inputs)
      6 
      7 inputs, outputs

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in
_call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)    1128         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks    1129              or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1130             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)    1131         # Do not call functions when jit is used    1132         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids, position_ids, head_mask, inputs_embeds, start_positions, end_positions, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)   1860     1861         logits = self.qa_outputs(sequence_output)
-> 1862         start_logits, end_logits = logits.split(1, dim=-1)    1863         start_logits = start_logits.squeeze(-1).contiguous()    1864         end_logits = end_logits.squeeze(-1).contiguous()

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

But when I initialize the model with from a different repo i.e indolem/indobert-base-uncased, it runs no problem. I only changed the from_pretrained value.

Has this ever happened to anyone? Is it a problem with the model I’m trying to load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like they haven't cleaned up the config before uploading. The [config.json](https://huggingface.co/indobenchmark/indobert-base-p1/blob/main/config.json) contains a `num_labels:5` which initializes your model with an output layer output size of 5. You can fix that as follows:

```py
from transformers import AutoModelForQuestionAnswering, AutoTokenizer, AutoConfig

model_id = 'indobenchmark/indobert-base-p1'

# Model with wrong output shape
model = AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained(model_id)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)
print(model.qa_outputs)

# Model with correct output shape
config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(model_id)
config.num_labels = 2
model = AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained(model_id, config=config)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)
print(model.qa_outputs)


context = 'Sindrom Bazex: acrokeratosis paraneoplastica.'
question = 'Nama sinonim dari Acrokeratosis paraneoplastica.'

inputs = tokenizer(question, context, return_tensors='pt')
outputs = model(**inputs)
print(outputs.keys())
```

Output:

```
Linear(in_features=768, out_features=5, bias=True)
Linear(in_features=768, out_features=2, bias=True)
odict_keys(['start_logits', 'end_logits'])
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming! I also found out and realized when I dug deeper into Huggingface's scripts.